# Wrapping executable that takes input and output files such that it uses stdin and stdout instead (using named pipes)

Tags: go, named-pipes, mkfifo

I'm trying to wrap an executable that takes an input and output file paths as arguments, such that it will be possible to provide the input and output as `stdin` and `stdout`.

I've written a short script in Go that attempts to do this, but for some reason which eludes me, it hangs forever.

See https://goplay.space/#le6Hexg1ZiJ.

I can add more details as required, but to start, I'd rather not pollute the question with possibly less relevant information.

EDIT: As requested, I'm adding the code here.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

/*
    Expected behavior:

    # Terminal 1
    $ go run main.go

    # Terminal 2
    $ cat inPipe > outPipe

    The go program is writing to inPipe and reading from outPipe

    Actual behavior: The program stalls
*/

func main() {
    eg := &errgroup.Group{}

    inPipe := "inPipe"
    outPipe := "outPipe"

    if err := syscall.Mkfifo(inPipe, 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(inPipe)

    if err := syscall.Mkfifo(outPipe, 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(outPipe)

    fIn, err := os.OpenFile(inPipe, os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeNamedPipe)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer fIn.Close()

    eg.Go(func() error {
        _, err := io.Copy(fIn, strings.NewReader("123"))
        return err
    })

    fOut, err := os.OpenFile(outPipe, os.O_RDONLY, os.ModeNamedPipe)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer fOut.Close()

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

    eg.Go(func() error {
        _, err := io.Copy(buf, fOut)
        return err
    })

    if err := eg.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, buf); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code to the question by editing it.

Comment: You need to open the pipes as non-blocking, or your `Open` call just sits there waiting for the other end to show up. See this [pipes 101 with Go](http://www.albertoleal.me/posts/golang-pipes.html) for more details. I would recommend you get one pipe right before trying both.

Comment: @marc I actually did try adding `syscall.O_NONBLOCK` to the file mode but it causes an error: `device not configured`. I did go through getting each pipe working on it's own first which culminated in the code I posted above. The weird thing is that if I run the code, then do this in two different terminals: `$ cat inPipe` and `$ echo 123 > outPipe`, then the code progresses as expected, but if I try to do it in one command, e.g `$ cat inPipe > outPipe` then Open still hangs. Not sure why.